# Linear quation system solver

Tags: c++, parsing

I've done an equation system that takes as input the equations (you choose the number of equations), and gives as output the values of the unknowns.

I splitted the code in four files:

-equation class(move all to left member and acquire values)

-matrix class(find determinants)

-equations system class(craft matrices to find all the determinants)

-the main() asks for the equations

**main.cpp**

```
#include "EquationSystem.h"

int main()
{

    vector<string> equations;
    string nEq;

    cout << "Quante equazioni? ";

    getline(cin, nEq);
    stringstream ss;
    ss << nEq;
    int n;
    if (ss >> n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            string eq;
            cout << "Inserisci l'equazione numero " << i + 1 << " : ";
            getline(cin, eq);
            equations.push_back(eq);
        }
        EquationSystem system(equations);
        system.solve();
    }
    else cout << "ERROR\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Equation.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Equation
{
private:
    string equation;
    string leftMember, rightMember;
    map<string, double> unknowns;
    void elaborate(string &member, bool isLeft)
    {
        int unkCount = count_if(member.begin(), member.end(), isalpha);
        int prevUnkPos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < unkCount; i++)
        {
            int unkPos = find_if(member.begin() + prevUnkPos, member.end(), isalpha) - member.begin();
            if (!isdigit(member[unkPos - 1]) && !isalpha(member[unkPos - 1]))
                member.insert(unkPos, "1");
            prevUnkPos = find_if(member.begin() + prevUnkPos, member.end(), isalpha) - member.begin() + 1;
        }
        cout << member << endl;

        this->parse(member, isLeft);
    }
    void parse(string &member, bool isLeft)
    {
        istringstream iss(member);
        while ((int)iss.tellg() != EOF)
        {
            double coef, pow;
            char let, powSign;

            iss >> coef;
            stringstream ss;
            while (isalpha(iss.peek()))
            {
                iss >> let;
                ss << let;
                if (iss.peek() == '^')
                {
                    iss >> powSign >> pow;
                    ss << powSign << pow;
                }
            }
            if (!isLeft)
                coef *= -1;
            unknowns[ss.str()] += coef;
        }
    }
public:
    friend class EquationSystem;
    Equation(string equation)
    {
        this->equation = equation;
        if (this->equation.find_first_of("=") == string::npos)
            cout << "NOT AN EQUATION\n";
        else
        {
            this->leftMember = this->equation.substr(0, this->equation.find_first_of("="));
            this->rightMember = this->equation.substr(this->equation.find_first_of("=") + 1, this->equation.length());
            this->elaborate(leftMember, 1);
            this->elaborate(rightMember, 0);
        }
    }

};
```

**EquationSystem.h**

```
#include "Equation.h"
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <set>

class EquationSystem
{
private:
    vector<Equation> equations;
    vector<string> unknowns;
    map<string, double> solutions;
public:
    EquationSystem(vector<string> equation)
    {

        set<string> unk;
        for (auto i : equation)
            this->equations.push_back(Equation(i));
        for (auto i : equations)
        {
            for (auto j : i.unknowns)
                unk.insert(j.first);
        }
        unknowns.assign(unk.rbegin(), unk.rend());
    }
    void solve()
    {
        double det = toMatrix("").det();
        for_each(unknowns.begin(), unknowns.end() - 1, [this, det](string unknown) {solutions[unknown] = toMatrix(unknown).det() / det; });
        for (auto i : solutions)
        {
            cout << i.first << " e' uguale a " << i.second << endl;
        }
    }
    Matrix toMatrix(string toChange)
    {
        vector<vector<double>> nums(equations.size(), vector<double>(unknowns.size() - 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < equations.size(); i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            for_each(unknowns.begin(), unknowns.end() - 1, [this, &nums, i, &j, toChange](string unknown) {if (unknown == toChange) nums[i][j] = -equations[i].unknowns[""]; else nums[i][j] = equations[i].unknowns[unknown];   j++; });
        }
        Matrix mat(nums);
        cout << "Il determinante ";
        if (!(toChange == ""))
            cout << "di " << toChange << " ";
        cout << "e' \n";
        cout << mat << "        = " << mat.det() << endl << endl;
        return mat;
    }
};
```

**Matrix.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
private:
    vector<vector<double>> mat;
    Matrix algComp(int x, int y)
    {
        Matrix algComp(this->mat);

        for_each(algComp.mat.begin(), algComp.mat.end(), [x](vector<double> &row) {row.erase(row.begin() + x); });
        algComp.mat.erase(algComp.mat.begin() + y);

        return algComp;

    }
public:
    Matrix(vector<vector<double>> &matrix)
    {
        this->mat = matrix;
    }
    double det()
    {
        double det = 0;
        if (mat.size() > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mat.size(); i++)
            {
                det += pow(-1, i)*mat[0][i] * algComp(i, 0).det();
            }
            return det;
        }
        else return mat[0][0];
    }
    vector<double> &operator[](int n)
    {
        return mat[n];
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Matrix m)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.mat.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m.mat[i].size(); j++)
            {
                os << right << setw(3) << m[i][j] << " ";
            }
            if (!(i == m.mat.size() - 1))
                os << endl;
        }
        return os;
    }
};
```

How does it look like?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Feel free to write that down in an answer. Logic should indeed be in `.cpp` files, not in `.hpp` or `.h` files. Including them is quite common in larger projects though, it's only uncommon in small, one-off programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Algorithm**, while theoretically correct, from the computational standpoint is arguably the worst possible. Its time complexity is exponential, and it is numerically unstable.

**Naming** is very confusing. For example,

```
Matrix algComp(int x, int y)
{
    Matrix algComp(this->mat);
    ....
```

is very hard to follow that `algComp` is a matrix, and not a recursive call. It is also very unclear what `algComp`, `toChange`, `elaborate` stand for.

**One-liners** like

```
        for_each(unknowns.begin(), unknowns.end() - 1, [this, &nums, i, &j, toChange](string unknown) {if (unknown == toChange) nums[i][j] = -equations[i].unknowns[""]; else nums[i][j] = equations[i].unknowns[unknown];   j++; });
```

are absolutely unreadable. At least, consider

```
        for_each(unknowns.begin(), unknowns.end() - 1,
            [this, &nums, i, &j, toChange](string unknown) {
               if (unknown == toChange)
                   nums[i][j] = -equations[i].unknowns[""];
               else
                   nums[i][j] = equations[i].unknowns[unknown];
               j++;
            });
```

**Do not mix logic with UI.** Computation utility methods shall not print anything.

**PS:** It is perfectly all right to inline logic into the class definition.

Comment: You are saying that the algorithm is definitely not the best, but how can I effectively improve it?

Comment: @DanDan I don't think the algorithm can be improved. You need to change the approach radically: use Gauss elimination, or (if you feel really brave) a Jacoby method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with C++, so I'll make only one suggestion: Try to never put logic into a header (`.h` or `.hpp`) file, use source (`.cpp`) files for that purpose. Try to leave header files only for declarations and macros. In fact, since `#include` is only text inclusion, you can include `.cpp` files too if you absolutely need to include logic and definitions. Although that's not common in small projects like this, in larger projects it's more common (thanks @Mast!).

Also, one more point, try not use `using namespace std` in your code, it might cause namespace collision among other bad things (see this SO post: [Why is using namespace std considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). Try to use qualified names instead.

One more thing I found: `EquationSystem.h` and `main.cpp` have output in Spanish, while the others are in English. Has code been integrated from somewhere? Try not to have inconsistencies like this in code, especially in the UI.